# Is it possible to use the GE Link bulb without a wink hub?

Tags: home-automation

I am looking to automate the GE Link bulb but I do not have a Wink Hub. What I do have is a raspberry pi and an arduino. I've search but can't find any documentation about how to even get started on this. Is there anyone with a little bit of information that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several emerging standards for home automation, but from looking online it seems like th GE bulbs use Zigbee 1.2. The Wink hub then serves as a bridge between that and your home wifi network.

So if you want to communicate with the bulbs from a Raspberry Pi you will need to get a Zigbee module. If you want the Raspberry Pi to the communicate with other devices (say, your smartphone) you will also need to connect it to your home network via wifi or Ethernet.

Comment: Does it make more sense to root a wink hub and use Open HAB? I'm seeing the modules cost just as much as the hub.

Comment: @Alex: I don't know what you mean by "make more sense". The easiest thing to do is just buy a Wink hub and move on with your life. But since it seems like you want to make a project out of this you just have to decide what you want to do. If all you want to be able to do is turn on and off lights based on some programming logic you write, I don't think you'd need to root the Wink hub at all, since it has an API. I guess it really depends on what you think would be fun to do.

Answer (score 0):

i dont have a specific answer, but an arduino can do just about anything.  you should be able to put a piggyback wifi card on an uno and get them to talk anyhow.  the issue will be deciphering the coding to flash the arduino with.  i am sure a link uses something proprietary - GE isnt exactly open source.

Comment: The GE bulbs use the Zigbee protocol, not wifi. It's a totally different wireless style at a different frequency, I doubt a wifi card would be able to communicate.